# Rotating a sprite in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

So i wanted to rotate my sprite so that it was always looking at the mouse position. I am using the following code:

```
        public void draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        int mouse_x = Mouse.GetState().X;
        int mouse_y = Mouse.GetState().Y;
        float angles = Calc.getAngle(new Vector2(mouse_x, mouse_y));

        sb.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, angles, origins, SpriteEffects.None, 1);

    }

    //Calc.cs method
    public static float getAngle(this Vector2 v)
    {
        return (float)Math.Atan2(v.Y, v.X);
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle'

I thought I had the parameters correct, but obviously not. I can't figure out why it won't accept a vector for the position.

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) the method with 8 parameters takes a Rectangle, not a Vector2. There are some methods with 9 parameters and a Vector2. Are you missing a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an float number after "origins" for scale parameter of Draw method, and since you don't want to change your texture's size, scale should be 1.
(you need to use 6th overload of Draw method, which takes vector2 for position and a float for scale, another solution is using 5th overload, which in this case you have to use rectangle for position and there will be no need for scale)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by putting your vector.X and vector.Y  in new instance of rectangle and use the instance of rectangle instead of vector2 in spritebactch.Draw method